Kubernetes exit code 139 with .NET Core 6 app
We have a .NET Core 6 application that acts as a broker and talks with a Kafka Broker.
The app is dockerized and runs in a Kubernetes cluster.
When the app runs locally, it works well; when the app runs on production, it generally works, but sometimes we find a message like this:

The container last terminated with exit code 139 because of error

And the number of restarts is about 30/day.
I know this error is probably related to the app and not Kubernetes, but I cannot find anything on the app log.
It seems to silent crash and then restart.
Is there a way to track what event on the application code caused the crash?
Thanks in advance

Anyone found the solution for this issue, I am also facing similar issue for .Net 5 application.
